# Rails get record newest in many has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some model like this:

```
class LogActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :call_logs
   has_many :send_email_logs
   has_many :send_sms_logs
   ...
end

class CallLog < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :log_activity
end

class SendEmailLog < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :log_activity
end

class SendSmsLog < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :log_activity
end
```

Now, i want get one newest record in `:call_logs`, `:send_email_logs`, `:send_sms_logs`. How can i do that???

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this -

```
newest_call_log       = LogActivity.call_logs.last
newest_sent_email_log = LogActivity.send_email_logs.last
newest_sent_sms_log   = LogActivity.send_sms_logs.last
```

A single query alternative would be to do this -

```
newest_log = LogActivity.eager_load(:call_logs, :send_email_logs, :send_sms_logs).last
# The above will fire a query and fetch all the data you need, the below lines will segregate your data
newest_call_log       = newest_log.call_logs.last
newest_sent_email_log = newest_log.send_email_logs.last
newest_sent_sms_log   = newest_log.send_sms_logs.last
```

Comment: This use 3 query to get, i want 1 query T.T

Comment: @Toàn He uses 3 queries but they all efficiently. You can compare those 3 returned values to get the newest by `ruby` code easily. You still can get them in 1 query, but it is not efficiently unless you use STI on your 3 log tables.

Comment: I've updated the answer to align to what you are asking for, hope that helps. Depending on your use case you should consider STI like @yeuem1vannam suggests

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
LogActivity.joins(:call_logs, :send_email_logs, :send_sms_logs).where(log_activity_id: 1 or something)
```

For more explanation, you can look the rails [guide link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations)

Thanks

Comment: will it give all the three object ie. call_logs, send_email_logs, send_sms_logs or just the one object which is lastly created of all these three